# Laplace Transform of $ f(t)=ta^t $ and $ f(t)=t\sin(at) $

Tags: laplace-transform

How do I solve the Laplace transform of $ f(t)=ta^t $ and $ f(t)=t\sin(at) $?

Has some property that can help me solve or I can just revolve using the definition?

I can not solve... Help me please.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you need an alternative way to find the Laplace transform? I am pretty sure there aren't any tricks when using the definition.A table of Laplace transforms is typically made readily available, as the integrals involved in the definition are often challenging to compute. You should be able to find the answer to your question in such a table, but using the definition would be great practice as well.

Comment: I want to solve a practical way . The definition is not always practical to solve the Laplace transform ..

Answer (score 1):

The second is directly from the tables so I can't quite hint you on how to do it unless you want to prove it. $$\mathscr{L}_t\left [t\sin (at)\right ](s)=\dfrac{2as}{(a^2+s^2)^2}$$

But I can hint you about the first one. If $F(s)\colon =\mathscr{L}_t[f(t)](s)$ then the Laplace transform of $\mathrm{e}^{ct}f(t)$ is $F(s-c)$. All you gotta do is find what your $f(t),c$ are in your problem.